# How do i keep the button disabled even after the refresh of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>RollBack Resume UI</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function noBack(){window.history.forward()}
        noBack();
        window.onload=noBack;
        window.onpageshow=function(evt){if(evt.persisted)noBack()}
        window.onunload=function(){void(0)}
      </script>
    </head>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{base_url}}/admin/">Airflow</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/">DAGs</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Data Profiling <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/queryview/">Ad Hoc query</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/chart/">Charts</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/knownevent/">Known Events</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/slamiss/">SLA Instances</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/taskinstance/">Task Instances</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/log/">Logs</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/basejob/">Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/dagrun/">DAG Runs</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/pool/">Pools</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/configurationview/">Configuration</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/user/">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/connection/">Connections</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/variable/">Variables</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/xcom/">XComs</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Rollback <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/rollback/">Rollback </a></li>
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/rollbackresume/">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Docs <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Github</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/versionview/">Version</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <h3>RollBack Resume UI</h3>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col" >Dataset Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Dataset State</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         {% for i in qry%}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"> </th>
                   <td> {{ i.dataset_id }} </td>
                   <td> {{ i.dataset_state }} </td>
                </tr>
         {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
       <head>
        <div class="container">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadDoc()"> Resume operation </button>
         </div>>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function loadDoc(dataset_id) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept','text/html')
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length","22");
      xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({'operation' : 'inactive'}));
    }
    </script>
       </head>
    </html>
```

Explanation :
I have HTML page which displays some data from the DB. I also have a button which after clicking sends an HTTP post request, so soon after clicking the button, i am disabling the button, i want to to be disabled even after the refresh of the browser. I don't know how do i do it, Can someone help me in this situation?

Comment: What about the post request you sent? won't this be required.

Comment: store some key in localStorage and check it on page ready.

Comment: Hi, And when would you want to enable it again? 
If you want to disable it until session ends, you can use local storage or session storage as per requirement to save a flag indicating if button is clicked. The button can be disabled based on flag.
If you want to disable the button for ever if clicked once, then you will have to save in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to achieve this.

When your user submit the form, you would persist state to LocalStorage that controls the submit buttons disabled attribute. On page load, you would query `LocalStorage` for this state, and initialize the disabled attribute accordingly:

```js
// Query storage state and set disabled attribute if local storage has 
// myBtnDisabled key value of "true"
if(window.localStorage && localStorage.getItem("myBtnDisabled") === "true") {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}

function loadDoc(dataset_id) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
    
  // Set state to cause the button to be disabled in future refreshes
  if(window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem("myBtnDisabled", "true");
  }
  
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/html')
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", "22");
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
    'operation': 'inactive'
  }));
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a session variable after the request and check if the variable is set the disable the button or if you want to handle it from javascript the use cookies .

Answer (score 0):

You can use session or localStorage and check those condition in function and call that function when your page is loaded or ready e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(function(){
         if(localStorage.getItem('your_variable)){
            $('#mybtn').prop('disabled', false);
          }else{
            $('#mybtn').prop('disabled', true);
          }
       })

 });
```

Hope this helps.